# How to specify 64 bit integers in c

Tags: c, 64-bit, sizeof

I'm trying to use 64 bit integers in C, but am getting mixed signals as to whether it should be possible.

When I execute the printf:

```
printf("Size of long int:%d\nSize of long long int:%d\n\n",(int)sizeof(long int), (int)sizeof(long long int));
```

The response I get is:

Size of long int:4
Size of long long int:8

This makes me feel that a long long int has 8 bytes = 64 bits.

However, when I try to declare the following variables:

```
long long int a2 = 0x00004444;
long long int b2 = 0x000044440;
long long int c2 = 0x0000444400;
long long int d2 = 0x00004444000;
long long int e2 = 0x000044440000;
long long int f2 = 0x0000444400004;
long long int g2 = 0x00004444000044;
long long int h2 = 0x000044440000444;
long long int i2 = 0x0000444400004444;
```

The last 4 variables (f2,g2,h2,i2) give me the error message:

warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type

I get the same result when I replace 'long long int' with 'int64_t'. I assume 'int64_t' was recognized, since it didn't generate any error messages of its own.

So, it appears my 8 byte long long int is really a 6 byte long long int, and I don't understand what I'm missing here. If it's any help, here is the information on my gcc compiler:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ gcc -v  
Using built-in specs.  
Target: i686-linux-gnu  
Configured with: ../src/configure -v   
--with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5'  
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs   
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++  
--prefix=/usr   
--program-suffix=-4.4   
--enable-shared   
--enable-multiarch   
--enable-linker-build-id   
--with-system-zlib   
--libexecdir=/usr/lib   
--without-included-gettext   
--enable-threads=posix   
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4   
--libdir=/usr/lib   
--enable-nls   
--with-sysroot=/ -  
-enable-clocale=gnu   
--enable-libstdcxx-debug   
--enable-objc-gc   
--enable-targets=all 
--disable-werror   
--with-arch-32=i686   
--with-tune=generic   
--enable-checking=release   
--build=i686-linux-gnu   
--host=i686-linux-gnu   
--target=i686-linux-gnu  
Thread model: posix  
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

If anyone knows how (or if) 64 bit integers are accessible to me, I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks....

Comment: As an alternative to the `LL` suffix, compiling with `-std=c99` ought to work too. In C99, a hexadecimal integer constant has type `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` if it is too large to fit in `(unsigned) long int`, but fits in `(unsigned) long long int`. No suffix needed.

Comment: One point, that should be mentioned here, is that the problem aren't the long long int variables `f2` to `i2`, but the integer literals you specified. In C89 a integer literal without a specified suffix is of type `int` if the given value fits into that type, else it has the type `long int`. The problem is, that `0x0000444400004` doesn't fit neither into the `int` or the `long int` type and this is what the compiler is complaining about. The assignment isn't the problem here, you assign a `long int` to a `long long int`. As Daniel writes, c99 solves this by allowing `long long` literals.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I added that.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `stdint.h` for specific sizes of integer data types, and also use appropriate suffixes for integer literal constants, e.g.:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t i2 = 0x0000444400004444LL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I'll have to experiment with this. The 'LL' suffix seemed sufficient. So, I now have to figure out/research if the i64_t is used mainly for readability or to truly force *exactly* 64 bits tan integer.

Comment: `int64_t` is both robust and portable. `long long int` is not.

Comment: In theory, `int64_t` is optional. However, `int_least64_t` and `long long int` are (as of C99) mandated by the standard and must have at least 64 bits (63 value bits + sign bit).

Comment: I can see long long int not being robust, but how is it not portable? Unless you mean not portable = maybe/maybe not 64 bits. Am I understanding correctly? Right now, my impression is int64_t = 64 bits always & everywhere. long long int = 64 bits or more depending on your implementation of C.

Comment: With C99 `long long int` is at least 64 bits, so it depends on how portable you want to be - if you can assume C99 then you're OK. But to me it seems to be a "no brainer" that if you need an explicit size then that should be expressed explicitly - it doesn't cost you anything, it's more readable and self-explanatory, and it tends to be more portable.

Comment: How do you use "appropriate" suffixes when one architecture has 64 bit `L` suffix and another has 32 bit `L` suffix but a 64 bit `LL` suffix? This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @doug65536: `LL` is 64 bits in both the cases that you give.

Comment: @doug65536 Use `INT64_C(0x0000444400004444)` for a constant at least 64-bit.  The "appropriate" suffixes will be added.

Comment: `int64_t i2 = 0x0000444400004444LL;` would be fine without the `LL`.  `LL` serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 28):

Try an `LL` suffix on the number, the compiler may be casting it to an intermediate type as part of the parse. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html

`long long int i2 = 0x0000444400004444LL;`

Additionally, the the compiler is discarding the leading zeros, so `0x000044440000` is becoming `0x44440000`, which is a perfectly acceptable 32-bit integer (which is why you aren't seeing any warnings prior to `f2`).

Answer (score 6):

Use `int64_t`, that portable C99 code.

```
int64_t var = 0x0000444400004444LL;
```

For printing:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("blabla %" PRIi64 " blabla\n", var);
```

Comment: Thanks, the 'LL' suffix seems to be the simplest working solution. So, I now need to figure out how much of the purpose of int64_t is for readability and how much is to truly enforce 64 bits.

Comment: @user1245262, use int64_t when you must have 64bits - ie some data  field is exactly this long. Use long long when you need more than long - then you will still be ok on the 256 bit machine next year!

Comment: long long int is *at least* 64 bits. int64_t is *exactly* 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks... that's the difference that makes sense to me.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath C doesn't define at least for any builtin type. The only requirement is sizeof(char)==1 and  sizeof(long long)>=sizeof(long)>=sizeof(int)>=sizeof(char). If you know your platform than LL is a solution. If you need cross-platform code you should test that long long is at least 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

> How to specify 64 bit integers in c

Going against the *usual* good idea to appending `LL`.

Appending `LL` to a *integer constant* will insure the type is at least as wide as `long long`.  If the *integer constant* is octal or hex, the constant will become `unsigned long long` if needed.

**If ones does not care to specify too wide a type, then `LL` is OK.**  else, read on.

`long long` may be wider than 64-bit.

Today, it is rare that `long long` is not 64-bit, yet C specifies `long long` to be *at least* 64-bit.  So by using `LL`, in the future, code may be specifying, say, a 128-bit number.

C has *Macros for integer constants* which in the below case will be type `int_least64_t`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
  int64_t big = INT64_C(9223372036854775807);
  printf("%" PRId64 "\n", big);
  uint64_t jenny = INT64_C(0x08675309) << 32;  // shift was done on at least 64-bit type 
  printf("0x%" PRIX64 "\n", jenny);
}
```

output

```
9223372036854775807
0x867530900000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Append ll suffix to hex digits for 64-bit (long long int), 
   or ull suffix for unsigned 64-bit (unsigned long long)

Answer (score 0):

**Questionable compiler error**

Since C99, all 4 constants should compile as is without warning.  No `LL` suffix needed.

```
long long int f2 = 0x0000444400004;
long long int g2 = 0x00004444000044;
long long int h2 = 0x000044440000444;
long long int i2 = 0x0000444400004444;
// The last 4 variables (f2,g2,h2,i2) give me the error message:
// warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
```

With C89, compiler should complain about `long long`, unless `long long` available as a compiler extension.  In that case, need for a suffix depends on the compiler extension.