# convert sha 256 hash to number in c

Tags: c, hash, type-conversion

I have a 16MB file. I want to take 16-byte chuck of the data each time, using SHA256 to hash it, and then use the result to point to the next location of the 16-byte chunk to be hashed.

For example,

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define BLOCKSIZE 1048576
#define SUBBLOCKSIZE 16

int main(void) {

  SHA256_CTX ctx;
  int SHA256_Init(SHA256_CTX *ctx);
  u_int8_t results[32];

  FILE *infile;
  char buf[SUBBLOCKSIZE];
  int bufsize = SUBBLOCKSIZE;

  infile = fopen("sample.dat", "r");
  int i = 0;
  int n;

  while (fread(buf, SUBBLOCKSIZE, 1, infile) != NULL) {
    SHA256_Init(&ctx);
    n = strlen(buf);
    SHA256_Update(&ctx, (u_int8_t *)buf, n);
    SHA256_Final(results, &ctx);

    //fseek here.....

    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In my code, 'results' is the hash result of SHA256. I want to convert it to a 256-bit number and mod it by 1024(or some other arbitrary integer number). Then I use the result as an input in fseek to locate to the next file pointer.

I'd like to know how can I convert 'results' to a 256-bit number?

Comment: `resulta[32]` _is_ your 256 bit number. If you want it's hexadecimal representation, use the `SHA224_Data` function.

Comment: @MichaelWalz So I can use it? For example, int newloc = results % 1024; ?

Comment: If you wanna have a 256-bit _number_ (represented as a normal number, not an array), be prepared to write your own set of functions for long math and do the computations dealing only with `results`.

Comment: Of course not. Why do you want to get the digest modulo 1024 ?

Comment: @Luke, `int newloc = results % 1024;` won't work since here you're `mod`ding the _address_ of `results`

Comment: Recommend to _not_ "convert 'results' to a 256-bit number".  Instead create code that takes an array of bytes and does the mod.

Comment: This is strange that you're trying to compute a mod 1024. The result will be greater or equal to zero, but less than 1024, which fits into an integer, while a 256-bit number does not. So, you're modding an _extremely huge_ number to get a _tiny_ one, which means you're going to loose a lot of entropy.

Comment: "some other arbitrary integer number" --> what is the range of this number (smallest, largest)?

Comment: Why do you want to compute 256-bit hashes of 128-bit chunks?

Comment: I designed an algorithm that jumps over data. The rough idea is that the data is first AES encrypted. And then hashed. My question is focus on the hashing and type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer would be to use a library that handles big integers. For C [the OpenSSL `BN_` functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/bn.html) perform operations on Big Numbers, to name just an obvious one.

The not-so direct answer is to simply use 64 bits/8 bytes (leftmost) bits of the 256 bits/32 bytes of the resulting array and put it into a 64 bit "long" number ([`int64_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606455/how-to-specify-64-bit-integers-in-c) is probably best). Then you can simply retrieve the modulo `x` of that value using the `%` operator.

Beware that the result is *not* well distributed over the limit `x` that are not powers of two. In that case you may need to discard any number `r` that is equal or larger than `x * n` where `n` is the maximum value where `x * n` still fits into 64 bits. If you don't discard those values then you have a (tiny) higher chance that the result will be a lower value.

Of course if your result is exactly a power `p` of 2 then you might as well take the `p` (leftmost) bits and interpret those bits as an unsigned integer of a size the same or higher.

Comment: I read the BN documentation and only found the conversion from BN to other format such as BN_bn2bin(). Is there a function that could convert bytes to BN?

Comment: What about [`BN_bin2bn`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html) (and yes, the OpenSSL API documentation sucks, it even says so on my profile page).

Comment: Note that the above doesn't contain any other cryptographic recommendations. For instance, SHA-256 is void of *cycles* where the output is identical to a previous input. That's of course not the case for your scheme; it's perfectly possible to regenerate the same location and get into an endless loop. To avoid that you could use a sorting algorithm instead (using a pseudo random number generator). As I don't know the use case I cannot comment on that.